# webApp not loading Passenger + nginx + ruby 2.6.8 + rails 6.0.4 @digitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, passenger-nginx

I recently upgrade ruby version and Rails version to 2.6.8 and 6.0.4 respectively, the app is running fine when I run it through "rails start" command, but when we invoke it through passenger through nginx then the app does not load and throws errors.

I used rvm to install ruby-2.6.8,
I used rvmsudo to start nginx: rvmsudo service nginx start/restart.
I Used latest bundler which was giving bundler version issue and then I downgraded it to bundler-1.17.3 then bundler version issue resolved but this issue came.
nginx - 1.14.x
passenger- 6.0.10
ruby- 2.6.8
rails- 6.0.4

```
[passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (nobody) and Ruby interpreter...
 (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
 Warning: compilation didn not succeed. To learn why, read this file:
 /tmp/passenger_native_support-1s7i1rz.log
 [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
 (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
 Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.10/rubyext-ruby-2.6.8-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 
 Trying next mirror...
 Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.10/rubyext-ruby-2.6.8-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 
 Trying next mirror...
 Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.10/rubyext-ruby-2.6.8-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
[passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can not compile or download) 
    --> Passenger will still operate normally.
    Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using "sudo" instead of "rvmsudo". When using RVM, you are always supposed to use "rvmsudo" instead of "sudo!".

Please try rerunning this program using "rvmsudo". If that does not help, please contact this programs author for support.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:82: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f53c62fb210
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [x86_64-linux]


-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in "<main>"
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in "<module:PhusionPassenger>"
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in "<module:App>"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:390:in "run_block_and_record_step_progress"
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in "block in <module:App>"
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in "preload_app"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in "run_load_path_setup_code"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:536:in "running_bundler"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:541:in "rescue in running_bundler"
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:82:in "ruby_command"

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f4bc7875b7d RBP: 0x00000007fffffff0 RSP: 0x00007ffe0577d4f0
 RAX: 0x000055bee28728e0 RBX: 0x00007f53c62fb210 RCX: 0x00007f53c62fb218
 RDX: 0x00007f4bc62fb220 RDI: 0x00007f4bc63fada8 RSI: 0x00007f4bc63fada8
  R8: 0x000055bee202a350  R9: 0x000055bee20a02e8 R10: 0x00007f4bc63fada8
 R11: 0x00007f4bc62fb219 R12: 0x00000000fffffffe R13: 0x00007f4bc62fb218
 R14: 0x00007f4bc7b90b98 R15: 0x0000000000000000 EFL: 0x0000000000010202

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(rb_vm_bugreport+0x769) [0x7f4bc78859d9] vm_dump.c:715
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(rb_bug_context+0xe7) [0x7f4bc76c7777] error.c:609
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(sigsegv+0x42) [0x7f4bc77ece72] signal.c:998
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(0x7f4bc7259040) [0x7f4bc7259040]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(rb_vm_exec+0x72d) [0x7f4bc7875b7d] vm.c:2094
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(ruby_exec_internal+0xd6) [0x7f4bc76ce516] eval.c:262
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f4bc76d0bed] eval.c:326
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.6(ruby_run_node+0x2e) [0x7f4bc76d41ae] eval.c:318
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/ruby(main+0x5b) [0x55bee0a2a94b] ./main.c:42

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: Passenger AppPreloader: /home/twirll/web/apps/twirllapp

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    5 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    6 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    7 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    8 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    9 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   10 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/errors.rb
   11 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb
   12 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   13 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   14 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   15 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   16 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb
   17 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb
   18 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb
   19 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/common.rb
   20 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb
   21 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/file.rb
   22 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ftp.rb
   23 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/http.rb
   24 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/https.rb
   25 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ldap.rb
   26 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   27 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/mailto.rb
   28 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri.rb
   29 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb
   30 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
   31 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
   32 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   33 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   34 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/util.rb
   35 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb
   36 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   37 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   38 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb
   39 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   40 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb
   41 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb
   42 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   43 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb
   44 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
   45 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
   46 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
   47 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checker.rb
   48 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
   49 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
   50 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
   51 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
   52 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/key_error_checker.rb
   53 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
   54 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/formatters/plain_formatter.rb
   55 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb
   56 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb
   57 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
   58 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils/version.rb
   59 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
   60 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb
   61 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb
   62 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
   63 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/base64.rb
   64 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
   65 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
   66 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
   67 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
   68 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
   69 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
   70 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/shellwords.rb
   71 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
   72 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb
   73 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/download.rb
   74 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
   75 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
   76 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
   77 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable/impl.rb
   78 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb
   79 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/json.rb
   80 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
   81 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so
   82 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb
   83 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
   84 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
   85 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
   86 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb
   87 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
   88 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
   89 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
   90 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
   91 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
   92 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
   93 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
   94 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
   95 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
   96 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
   97 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
   98 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/version.rb
   99 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/compatibility_guard.rb
  100 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb
  101 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/text.rb
  102 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
  103 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
  104 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
  105 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb
  106 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
  107 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb
  108 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb
  109 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendored_fileutils.rb
  110 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/errors.rb
  111 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/environment_preserver.rb
  112 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/plugin/api.rb
  113 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/plugin.rb
  114 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/git.rb
  115 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/installed.rb
  116 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/specific_file.rb
  117 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/local.rb
  118 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/lock.rb
  119 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source/vendor.rb
  120 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/source.rb
  121 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
  122 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/match_platform.rb
  123 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
  124 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/build_metadata.rb
  125 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb
  126 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/settings.rb
  127 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui.rb
  128 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/silent.rb
  129 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/rg_proxy.rb
  130 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/feature_flag.rb
  131 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source.rb
  132 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb
  133 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/git.rb
  134 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
  135 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
  136 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb
  137 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb
  138 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dependency.rb
  139 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
  140 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb
  141 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source_list.rb
  142 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/metadata.rb
  143 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ruby_version.rb
  144 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
  145 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/index.rb
  146 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb
  147 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb
  148 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/compatibility.rb
  149 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/gem_metadata.rb
  150 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb
  151 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/errors.rb
  152 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/action.rb
  153 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_edge_no_circular.rb
  154 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_vertex.rb
  155 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/delete_edge.rb
  156 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/detach_vertex_named.rb
  157 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/set_payload.rb
  158 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/tag.rb
  159 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/log.rb
  160 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/vertex.rb
  161 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb
  162 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/state.rb
  163 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/specification_provider.rb
  164 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/resolution_state.rb
  165 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb
  166 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb
  167 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb
  168 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo.rb
  169 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/vendored_molinillo.rb
  170 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/resolver/spec_group.rb
  171 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/resolver.rb
  172 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/gemspec.rb
  173 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb
  174 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  175 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/remote_specification.rb
  176 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/stub_specification.rb
  177 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
```

I also checked this log file /tmp/passenger_native_support-1s7i1rz.log

```
# current user is: nobody
# mkdir -p /nonexistent/.passenger/native_support/6.0.10/ruby-2.6.8-x86_64-linux
Encountered permission error, but no more directories to try. Giving up.
-------------------------------
```

gem env

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.8 (2021-07-07 patchlevel 205) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.8@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.8/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

Can someone please help me here, I am kind of stuck in this activity.
let me know if need any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the log in detail,
on the 4th line the below log file was mentioned, it had captured the error, and the error was about a permission of a folder so that certain files can be written into it.

```
/tmp/passenger_native_support-1s7i1rz.log
```

I hope this helps someone who is looking for similar problem. the characters at last in filename 1s7i1rz may vary everytime this problem appears.